# How to locate a string while is running .read() on Python?

Tags: python, string, locate

i'm using urllib2

```
try:
    msmalvo = urllib2.urlopen(website)
except URLError as e:
    msmalvo = e

if msmalvo.code == 200:
    if msmalvo.read() == '<head>':
        print 'Exits!'

    else:
        print 'Don't exist'

else:
    print ' '
    print msmalvo.code, ':/'
```

the idea is to confirm that the string "\head/" was found in the source code of a page.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
'<head>' in msmalvo.read()
```

instead of:

```
msmalvo.read() == '<head>'
```

Comment: I don't get it '-'. Can you explain ?

Comment: Ahh! I'm so dumb! hahaha. I'm new in python and I thought that "in" is only used in "for" statement xD! Thanks Kabia ;)!